# Rtools and untar2 warming message in R from devtools/github install

Tags: r, github

I'm developing an R package that will be available on github, but when I did a test download/install on another computer using devtools::install_github I received the warning messages below. The package seems to work correctly, but I would prefer it if people did not receive warnings when installing it. What is causing these warnings and can I modify my package to avoid them?

Also, it seems like it is downloading a developmental version of the package instead of just the package itself (I suspect I have something set wrong).

Here are the warnings:

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

In R CMD INSTALL
Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers

Update: Reinstalling Rtools fixed the Rtools warning, but not the untar2 warnings
here is the package https://github.com/donaldtmcknight/microDecon

Comment: Perhaps share the github link to your package so people may try to reproduce your warning...?

Comment: I have updated the question with a link https://github.com/donaldtmcknight/microDecon

Answer (score 0):

@yt1300: I can't reproduce your warnings.

```r
devtools::install_github("donaldtmcknight/microDecon")
#> Downloading GitHub repo donaldtmcknight/microDecon@master
#>   
   checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmphWCjio/remotes2d475ebd1f6/donaldtmcknight-microDecon-78f3757/DESCRIPTION’ ...

✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmphWCjio/remotes2d475ebd1f6/donaldtmcknight-microDecon-78f3757/DESCRIPTION’
#> 

─  preparing ‘microDecon’:
#> 

   checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...

✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
#> 

─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
#> 

─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
#> ─  looking to see if a ‘data/datalist’ file should be added
#> 

─  building ‘microDecon_1.0.0.tar.gz’
#> 


#> 
#> Installing package into '/home/rmagno/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5'
#> (as 'lib' is unspecified)
library(microDecon)
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Arch Linux
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3.8.0
#> LAPACK: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3.8.0
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=en_DK.utf8         LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] microDecon_1.0.0
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.0        knitr_1.20        magrittr_1.5     
#>  [4] usethis_1.4.0     devtools_2.0.1    pkgload_1.0.2    
#>  [7] R6_2.3.0          rlang_0.3.0.1     stringr_1.3.1    
#> [10] tools_3.5.1       pkgbuild_1.0.2    sessioninfo_1.1.1
#> [13] cli_1.0.1         withr_2.1.2       remotes_2.0.2    
#> [16] htmltools_0.3.6   yaml_2.2.0        assertthat_0.2.0 
#> [19] rprojroot_1.3-2   digest_0.6.18     crayon_1.3.4     
#> [22] processx_3.2.0    callr_3.0.0       fs_1.2.6         
#> [25] base64enc_0.1-3   ps_1.2.1          curl_3.2         
#> [28] testthat_2.0.1    glue_1.3.0        memoise_1.1.0    
#> [31] evaluate_0.12     rmarkdown_1.10    stringi_1.2.4    
#> [34] compiler_3.5.1    desc_1.2.0        backports_1.1.2  
#> [37] prettyunits_1.0.2
```

Comment: hmmm. It may be that something is configured wrong on the computer I was installing it on, but I'd still love to know exactly what is going on. Thanks for trying to replicate the warnings.